# Flutter: ImagePicker from gallery won't pop up on web in iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image-picker

I'm using the package image_picker on a flutter app to load a picture, and it works fine in the web when accessed by an Windows, MacOs, Android, but in the iOS (16.3) the pop up to choose the image won't show up.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import "package:image/image.dart" as img;

class ProgramScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProgramScreenState createState() => _ProgramScreenState();
}

class _ProgramScreenState extends State<ProgramScreen> {
  TextEditingController _destinationController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _subjectController = TextEditingController();

  late Uint8List _clipboardImage;
  bool hasImage = false;
  bool hasText = false;
  double heightImg = 1;
  double widthImg = 1;

  Future _getImageFromPicker() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, requestFullMetadata: false);
    var bytes = await image!.readAsBytes();
    var photoData = img.decodeImage(bytes);
    heightImg = photoData!.height * 0.5;
    widthImg = photoData.width * 0.5;
    setState(() {
      hasImage = true;
      hasText = false;
      _clipboardImage = bytes;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Destinatáio'),
                    controller: _destinationController,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Assunto'),
                    controller: _subjectController,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {},
                  child: Text('Enviar Grupo'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {},
                  child: Text('Enviar Todos'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 100),
            hasText
                ? Text(
                    "O conteúdo copiado não é uma imagem!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )
                : SizedBox(height: 1),
            !hasImage
                ? Column(children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {},
                      child: Text('Verificar área de transferência'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        _getImageFromPicker(); // Here is the function call
                      },
                      child: Text('Escolher da galeria'),
                    ),
                  ])
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: heightImg.toDouble(),
                        width: widthImg.toDouble(),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: MemoryImage(_clipboardImage),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Column(children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {},
                          child: Text('Verificar área de transferência'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 16),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            _getImageFromPicker(); // Here is the function call
                          },
                          child: Text('Escolher da galeria'),
                        ),
                      ])
                    ],
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm, locale pt-BR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

[the pop up supposed to apper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/884tz.jpg)

I tried to use older versions of the packages, but still have the same issue. Also, setting the "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell the reason why, but changing

```
onPressed: () async {
    _getImageFromPicker(); // Here is the function call
}
```

to

```
onPressed: () { // removed the async modifier
    _getImageFromPicker(); // Here is the function call
}
```

Solves the problem! Now the pop up shows up as expected